# Initial Deployment failed. Unable to pinpoint error with efficiency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to deploy a set of firebase functions. The project i am currently working on has a huge code base . I am facing an error as follows -
*Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Identifier 'project_manager' has already been declared*
Now i had to search each script manually to find this error .
Is there a more efficient way to pinpoint this error ? I even tried the --debug option while deploying but still it doesn't pinpoint the error.